# Python getting a list from a called python file

Tags: python, tensorflow, imagenet

In `task2.py` , I am executing a python file like this:

```
text = os.system("python new_image.py  --image_file " + "/home/roots/" + str(nc) + ".jpg --num_top_predictions 1")
```

The essential lines of `new_image.py` look like

```
def main(_):
    maybe_download_and_extract()
    image = (FLAGS.image_file if FLAGS.image_file else
            os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, 'cropped_panda.jpg'))
    score = run_inference_on_image(image)
    return score


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--model_dir',
        type=str,
        default='/tmp/imagenet',
        help="""\
        Path to classify_image_graph_def.pb,
        imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt, and
        imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt.\
        """
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--image_file',
        type=str,
        default='',
        help='Absolute path to image file.'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--num_top_predictions',
        type=int,
        default=5,
        help='Display this many predictions.'
    )
    FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

I have modified `classify_image.py` in tensorflow models imagenet such that `run_inference_on_image()` returns a list. I would now like to get this list in `task2.py`. How will I do this?

Comment: The code you provided is not really complete so I could not run and check the output. os.system is strongly discouraged for executing command. Use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) instead. Do you see your list score printed when you run new_image.py from command line? If so, you can use the subprocess.Popen constructor to capture this output and store it in a variable in task2.py.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to save the list as a temporary `pickle` file in `new_image.py`, and load the `pickle` file in `task2.py`. i.e.

```
# In new_image.py
import pickle
picklefile = open('temp.pkl', 'wb')

# Dump list to the pickle file
pickle.dump(listvariable, picklefile)
picklefile.close()
```

And,

```
# In task2.py
import pickle 
picklefile = open('temp.pkl', 'rb')
newlist_variable = pickle.load(picklefile)
picklefile.close()
```

I don't know if there is a way to share dynamic variables between two python processes. But if there is, I'd love to know!

Comment: Oops I think the order of the arguments was reversed. My bad. It should work now.